# Interface function throwing error when it call in the controller class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

> I creates a match repository interface and define a function with the
> return type ,but when I call that interface function through the
> instance of that repository that function show me an error ,please
> define an abstract function of that function, I don't know how to call
> that function. here below I provide the code details
> team.kt

```
package com.nilmani.ipldashboard2021.entity

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Transient

@Entity
data class Team(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val teamName:String="",
    val totalMatches:Long=-1,
    val wins:Long=-1,
    @Transient
    var matches:List<Match> = ArrayList()
)
```

> matchRepository.kt

```
package com.nilmani.ipldashboard2021.repository

import com.nilmani.ipldashboard2021.entity.Match
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository


interface MatchRepository : CrudRepository<Match,Long> {
    fun getByTeam1OrTeam2OrderByDateDesc(teamName1: String?,teamName2: String?,pageable: Pageable):List<Match>

    fun findLatestMatchesbyTeam(teamName: String?, count: Int): List<Match?>? {
        return getByTeam1OrTeam2OrderByDateDesc(teamName, teamName, PageRequest.of(0, count))
    }
}
```

> TeamController.kt

```
 @GetMapping("/team/{teamName}")
    fun getTeam(@PathVariable teamName: String): Team? {
        val team: Team = this.teamRepository.findByTeamName(teamName)
        team.matches = matchRepository.findLatestMatchesbyTeam(teamName, 4)
        return team
    }
```

> I got exact error at

```
team.matches = matchRepository.findLatestMatchesbyTeam(teamName,4)
```

> what is the reason for getting an error while calling
> findLatestMatchesbyTeam  function

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Team.matches is of type `List<Match>` but you are trying to assign `List<Match?>?` to it. You need to perform some kind of conversion from nullable types to non-nullable